# how to add a user using emailId to azure ad group using java spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We have a requirement to add members to azureAdGroup using users email through java spring boot application, we are using microsoft graph api rest call to add members to the azureAdGroup

Trying to add members to azureAdGroup by using the members email through java spring boot application,we are using the below code to add the members using the graph API

```
DirectoryObject directoryObject = new DirectoryObject();
directoryObject.id = "someName@someEmail.com"; // members emailId

graphClient.groups(adGroupId).members().references()
   .buildRequest()
   .post(directoryObject);
```

But we are getting the below error

CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 404Graph service exception Error code: Request_BadRequest
CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 404Error message: Invalid object identifier 'someName@someEmail.com'.
CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 404
CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 404POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/sgdbhjd-sndeh3h3-dasdnj3k3-dwb23/members/$ref
CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 404SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.0.0
CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 404SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.0.0

Could anyone please help how to add member to a azureAdGroup using members email through microsoft graphApi from java spring boot application

Could anyone please help how to add member to a azureAdGroup using user email through microsoft graphApi from java spring boot application

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** that: According to this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-add-a-member-to-a-group), to add users to the group you need to pass the id of the `directoryObject` not the UPN of the user.

For *sample*, I used [Graph Explorer APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to add the users to the group:

*Passed the UPN of the user and got the error:*

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/UPN"
}
```

[image]

**To resolve the error**, pass the `ObjectID` of the user not the UPN:

After passing the `ObjectID`, user got added successfully to the group:

[image]

[image]

Modify your code by passing the `ObjectID` of the user instead of UPN:

```java
DirectoryObject directoryObject = new DirectoryObject();
directoryObject.id = "ObjectID"; // members ObjectID

graphClient.groups(adGroupId).members().references()
   .buildRequest()
   .post(directoryObject);
```